# I searched passing params in a tags in your views but I did not find anything that can help me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple Rails app that has Users, Blogs, and Comments. The last thing I have to do is make a link on the blogs show page where comments show and have those links send the user to the `comment/:id/edit` page where they can edit their comment.

However, I'm not able to grab the comment ID correctly for some reason and even though I am getting thrown no errors I am not brought to the error form, just a blank web page that has my layout elements.

Here is my blogs controller's show action:

```
def show
  @blog = Blog.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
  # @current_comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is my comments controller's edit action:

```
def edit
  @comment = Comment.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

And here is where the link is in the Blogs show view:

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |c| %>
  <div><a href="/comments/#{c.id}/edit"><%= c.content %></a></div>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', "/comments/#{c.id}", method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

The delete function works, but when I try to grab the comment id in the same way for the link to the comment view it does not work. Instead of seeing a number in the url like `1`, `2`, or whatever the comment id is, I see the `#{c.id}` syntax. Any thoughts?

Comment: `#{c.id]`, you mean `/comments/#{c.id}`, on the delete link ?

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Delete', c, method: :delete %>`. You should avoid hardcoding paths in your application where possible.

Comment: admitting you defined  `resources :comments` in `routes.rb`, which you might have not done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean this part:

```
<div><a href="/comments/#{c.id}/edit"><%= c.content %></a></div>
```

That's because the `<div><a href="/comments/#{c.id}/edit">` part is outside a ERB block, therefore it is being interpreted as plain HTML, and that's what you see in the url. There's no variable expansion in plain HTML inside a ERB file.

Either use `link_to`:

```
<div><%= link_to c.content, "/comments/#{c.id}/edit" %></div>
```

or enclose the url part in ERB tags:

```
<div><a href="<%= "/comments/#{c.id}/edit" %>"><%= c.content %></a></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to point to Max's comment that hardcoding your paths is not a good habit to get into. He is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |c| %>
  <div>
    <%= link_to c.content, edit_comment_path(c) %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', c, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

In general you want to avoid hardcoding paths when possible as it makes your code more brittle and verbose.

As you have written it `"/comments/#{c.id}/edit"` is not even being evaluated since its not inside a ERB tag.